TexStudio Macro to replace a string inside selected text only
I am new to macros in TexStudio, and I am struggling to do some simple tasks, even after reading the documentation. I would like to automatically replace tabs with one space in a text. I can do this for the whole document using:
options = "g"
scope = cursor.selectedText()
editor.replace("\t",options,scope," ")

However, this does not replace the tabs in the selection. I would like to apply a macro only on selected text (actually, I would like to be able to apply any function to selected text in future macros, and I am struggling to understand how you use cursor.selectedText()in this context. Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions.

I use the following for this:
var scope = cursor.selectedText();
scope = scope.replace(/\t/g," ");
cursor.replaceSelectedText(scope);

